# Fizzbuzz Solution - complexity, readability, performance, lines, obfuscation... - .sort()

Tags: python, performance, functional-programming, fizzbuzz

The fizzbuzz challenge presents a lot of interesting questions for 'intermediate' programmers like myself. I have found that I don't actually know where to draw the line with, **complex** (hard to read but concise/efficient) code and **simple** (easy to read but not concise) code. Additionally, I actually do not know if my 'more efficient' code, actually performs better, or is just an expectation that `complexity=efficiency`. I am sure it doesn't. I made the example below after pondering this for a while and running a few tests, it is a solution using a lambda function inside the list comp. Sort of functional programming but without meaning...

```
output = ["fizzbuzz", "buzz", "fizz"]
iterList = lambda x: [x%i for i in [15, 5, 3]]
fizzBuzz = [output[iterList(x).index(0)] if 0 in iterList(x) else x for x in range(1, 101)]
print(fizzBuzz)
```

The main concern I have is in regard to computational efficiency. While this code is concise, reasonably complex and works. Would it actually perform any faster than a simple 5-to-10 line if, else function? Is there any point in designating the lambda function to a variable? Why would anyone sacrifice readability for complexity if there is no incentive? I have so many questions, but I guess thats the curve with programming; you think you're so good until you realise you're so bad.

Comment: I see a lot of "is this faster?" and not a lot of "I tested this to see if it's faster". You should be executing comparative performance tests if that's what you care about.

Comment: @Reinderien oh I did do performance tests, the solution above was marginally faster than a simple if, else conditional function. I was asking about performance in more of a general sense, rather than this specific example of fizzbuzz. I know how much these questions are hated though, and I respect your criticism as the question was definitely too open.

Comment: It's not a hated question at all, but certainly part of developing your skills is reaching for the right kind of test early in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to post a full review but multi-line code should not be posted into comments.

Your code is not as efficient as you think.

`lambda x: [x%i for i in [15, 5, 3]]`

The above line is very inefficient, you correctly identified the precedence of the moduli, but you did not use it to short circuit the executions.

For example, 30 is a multiple of 15 and it should generate "FizzBuzz", here we only need to check whether it is a multiple of 15, because it is a multiple of 15 we don't need and shouldn't check whether it is a multiple of 5 or 3, your code performs two more redundant checks that only worsens the performance.

25 is a multiple of 5, we first check whether it is a multiple of 15, it is not, we then check whether it is a multiple of 5, it is, so log "Buzz", done, there is absolutely no reason to check if it is a multiple of 3.

So you should write it like this:

```py
special = {15: 'FizzBuzz', 5: 'Buzz', 3: 'Fizz'}
for i in (15, 5, 3):
    if not number % i:
        var = special[i]
        break
```

`break` is a keyword that stops the loop, so it won't perform consecutive checks.

`special` is a `dict`, if you don't know what a dictionary is, look it up. It is much better than your double list indexing.

`for` loops also have an `else` clause, which executes after the loop is completed normally.

So if the number is not a multiple of any of the three, to get the number itself:

```py
special = {15: 'FizzBuzz', 5: 'Buzz', 3: 'Fizz'}
for i in (15, 5, 3):
    if not number % i:
        var = special[i]
        break
else:
    var = number
```

We normally wrap code we want to use repetitively inside functions, and use `return` to return the output back to the caller, `return` automatically stops the function so anything after it will not be executed.

The function:

```py
special = {15: 'FizzBuzz', 5: 'Buzz', 3: 'Fizz'}
def fizzbuzz(number):
    for i in (15, 5, 3):
        if not number % i:
            return special[i]
    return number
```

The function is much better than your three lines of code.

To print first 100 fizzbuzz values:

```py
special = {15: 'FizzBuzz', 5: 'Buzz', 3: 'Fizz'}
def fizzbuzz(number):
    for i in (15, 5, 3):
        if not number % i:
            return special[i]
    return number
for i in range(1, 101):
    print(fizzbuzz(i))
```

### ***Update***

---

If you only care about performance, here is a one-liner that uses generator expressions and `next` and I won't explain any of these two.

```py
SPECIAL = {15: 'FizzBuzz', 5: 'Buzz', 3: 'Fizz'}

def fizzbuzz(number):
    return next((label for x, label in SPECIAL.items() if not number % x), number)
```

Ultimate code golf:

```py
a='Fizz';b='Buzz';S={15:a+b,5:b,3:a};f=lambda n:next((l for c,l in S.items()if not n%c),n)
```

The human readable function is 170 bytes, the one-liner is 104 bytes and the golfed version is 90 bytes.

---

### ***Final Edit***

I did some testing and here are the results:

```
Python 3.9.10 (tags/v3.9.10:f2f3f53, Jan 17 2022, 15:14:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.28.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: special = {15: 'FizzBuzz', 5: 'Buzz', 3: 'Fizz'}
   ...: def fizzbuzz(number):
   ...:     for i in (15, 5, 3):
   ...:         if not number % i:
   ...:             return special[i]
   ...:     return number

In [2]: def fizz_buzz(n):
   ...:     for k, v in special.items():
   ...:         if not n % k:
   ...:             return v
   ...:     return n

In [3]: def FizzBuzz(number):
   ...:     return next((label for x, label in special.items() if not number % x), number)

In [4]: a='Fizz';b='Buzz';S={15:a+b,5:b,3:a};f=lambda n:next((l for c,l in S.items()if not n%c),n)

In [5]: fizzbuzz(255)
Out[5]: 'FizzBuzz'

In [6]: fizz_buzz(255)
Out[6]: 'FizzBuzz'

In [7]: FizzBuzz(255)
Out[7]: 'FizzBuzz'

In [8]: f(255)
Out[8]: 'FizzBuzz'
```

```
In [9]: %timeit fizzbuzz(255)
170 ns ± 0.897 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [10]: %timeit fizz_buzz(255)
256 ns ± 8.71 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [11]: %timeit FizzBuzz(255)
712 ns ± 13.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [12]: %timeit f(255)
688 ns ± 8.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [13]: import dis

In [14]: dis.dis(fizzbuzz)
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ((15, 5, 3))
              2 GET_ITER
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                24 (to 30)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (i)

  4           8 LOAD_FAST                0 (number)
             10 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             12 BINARY_MODULO
             14 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE         4

  5          16 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (special)
             18 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             20 BINARY_SUBSCR
             22 ROT_TWO
             24 POP_TOP
             26 RETURN_VALUE
             28 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4

  6     >>   30 LOAD_FAST                0 (number)
             32 RETURN_VALUE

In [15]: dis.dis(fizz_buzz)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (special)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              1 (items)
              4 CALL_METHOD              0
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    8 FOR_ITER                24 (to 34)
             10 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (k)
             14 STORE_FAST               2 (v)

  3          16 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
             18 LOAD_FAST                1 (k)
             20 BINARY_MODULO
             22 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE         8

  4          24 LOAD_FAST                2 (v)
             26 ROT_TWO
             28 POP_TOP
             30 RETURN_VALUE
             32 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            8

  5     >>   34 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
             36 RETURN_VALUE

In [16]: dis.dis(FizzBuzz)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (next)
              2 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (number)
              4 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <genexpr> at 0x00000269CA7D69D0, file "<ipython-input-3-ca9b85259fb4>", line 2>)
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 ('FizzBuzz.<locals>.<genexpr>')
             10 MAKE_FUNCTION            8 (closure)
             12 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (special)
             14 LOAD_METHOD              2 (items)
             16 CALL_METHOD              0
             18 GET_ITER
             20 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             22 LOAD_DEREF               0 (number)
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             26 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <genexpr> at 0x00000269CA7D69D0, file "<ipython-input-3-ca9b85259fb4>", line 2>:
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    2 FOR_ITER                22 (to 26)
              4 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (x)
              8 STORE_FAST               2 (label)
             10 LOAD_DEREF               0 (number)
             12 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             14 BINARY_MODULO
             16 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE         2
             18 LOAD_FAST                2 (label)
             20 YIELD_VALUE
             22 POP_TOP
             24 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            2
        >>   26 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE

In [17]: dis.dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (next)
              2 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (n)
              4 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <genexpr> at 0x00000269CAA370E0, file "<ipython-input-4-a067fdb714e4>", line 1>)
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 ('<lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr>')
             10 MAKE_FUNCTION            8 (closure)
             12 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (S)
             14 LOAD_METHOD              2 (items)
             16 CALL_METHOD              0
             18 GET_ITER
             20 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             22 LOAD_DEREF               0 (n)
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             26 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <genexpr> at 0x00000269CAA370E0, file "<ipython-input-4-a067fdb714e4>", line 1>:
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    2 FOR_ITER                22 (to 26)
              4 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (c)
              8 STORE_FAST               2 (l)
             10 LOAD_DEREF               0 (n)
             12 LOAD_FAST                1 (c)
             14 BINARY_MODULO
             16 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE         2
             18 LOAD_FAST                2 (l)
             20 YIELD_VALUE
             22 POP_TOP
             24 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            2
        >>   26 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE

In [18]:
```

My original function is the fastest, it takes only about 180 nanoseconds to complete.

As a general rule of thumb, if a function generates less bytecode, it is going to cost less time, because the function would be simpler for the CPU.

Code golfing is a bad thing, you use less characters but the logic is poorly thought because you can only pack so many ideas inside a few characters, so the compiler generates more bytecode to compensate.

And I don't use generator expressions, as you can see, generator expressions generate more code-objects which means you have more bytecode which in turn means performance degradation (very broadly speaking), because function calls are expensive.

Comment: Note that I wrote all of this on an Android phone and I don't have physical access to computers in nights (it was nighttime at the time of writing in my locale), I won't give you more details, the point is I wrote all of this without running or testing any of the code, but I know exactly what output it will have and how it will be executed.

Comment: Would be better to iterate over the constant (which should be named as a constant as well) rather than hardcoding `(15, 5, 3)`. Optionally -- and this is no better or worse, but it does fit within the OP's theme of evaluating tradeoffs between code readability and code compactness or even "coolness" -- it can also be expressed as `return next((label for x, label in SPECIAL.items() if not number % x), number)`.

Comment: @FMc I know I can write like that, but I am posting an answer to a question asked by a beginner and I am trying to keep the answer as human readable as possible...

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος thanks for the answer, that makes a lot of sense. I'm not quite sure if you were being sarcastic with all the very obvious stuff like what return is and what a dictionary is. But regardless, I appreciate the constructive criticism. The solution I went with was sort of just planned poorly on the spot. Using the basis I started on, I couldn't really remove the redundant iterations without reworking the solution. I did actually make something very similar to this about 10 mins after posting. Thankyou!

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).